# One-step flattening of an array in ruby

Tags: arrays, ruby

I am working out [this exercise](http://www.codewars.com/kata/flatten-1/ruby) in codewars, which is to flatten an array (up to one-level deep) so for example, I want to get the outputs:

```
[1,2,3] >> [1,2,3]

[[1,2],3] >> [1,2,3]

[[1,[2]],3] >> [1,[2],3]
```

I decided to use "inject" - where the next element gets added to the running total if that element is an array, or just pushed if it is not:

```
def flatten(array)
  array.inject([]) {|result,element| element.kind_of?(Array) result.concat(element) : result<<element}
end
```

Could anyone help explain why I am getting the following syntax error?

```
-e:3: syntax error, unexpected tIDENTIFIER, expecting '}'
... element.kind_of?(Array) result.concat(element) : result<
```

Comment: Also just to add, I'm not using the built in flatten method because it goes too deep: [[[3],[4],[5]],[9],[9],[8],[[1,2,3]]]) , [[3],[4],[5],9,9,8,[1,2,3]]

Comment: Your link requires a sign in, could you post the exercise?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You got an error cause you missed a `?` in ternary statement:

```
element.kind_of?(Array) ? result.concat(element) : result<<element
```

For your goal you can use `Array#flatten` with an argument:

```
array.flatten(1)
[[1,2],3].flatten(1)
=> [1, 2, 3]
[[1,[2]],3].flatten(1)
=> [1, [2], 3]
```

Comment: Thank you for both pieces of info!

Comment: @user25959 Be sure to mark the answer as correct if this answer worked for you.

Comment: Yes, absolutely. Stackoverflow made me wait 10+ minutes so I came back to it.